# Extract Only Unicode Characters from a String using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I want to extract Unicode characters from a String using Regular Expressions, removing ASCII, Numbers and Special Symbols from a String or a text file, is it possible using Regular Expression. For instance i want only Hindi or Chinese characters from a text taken from a news article.

Comment: ASCII *is* Unicode. For instance U+0000 is ASCII NUL. Any regex engine that supports numeric escapes lets you express the idea of "not ASCII" as, for instance, the character range `[\x80-]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated above, ASCII is a subset of Unicode, so the question doesn't quite make sense as-is. If you really want to remove all codepoints below `U+0080` from the string, that's easy:

```
re.sub(r"[\x00-\x7f]+", "", mystring)
```

If you want to keep only certain "whitelisted" characters, you need to specify precisely which codepoints to keep.

For example, to keep Devanagari codepoints (used for writing Hindi), you can use

```
re.sub(r"[^\u0900-\u097F]+", "", mystring)
```

or (Python 2, thanks @bobince for the heads-up!)

```
re.sub(ur"[^\u0900-\u097F]+", "", mystring)
```

You do need to make sure that you're working on a Unicode string, so don't forget to decode/encode your input string:

```
url = 'http://www.bhaskar.com/'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8-sig")
regex = re.compile(ur"[^\u0900-\u097F]+")
hindionly = regex.sub("foo", data)
print hindionly.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Is the POSIX class `[[:ascii:]]` valid in Python? Then you can use `[^[:ascii:]]+` to match all outside the common range.

Comment: @Jongware: No, Python does not recognize POSIX character classes.

Comment: Using hexadecimals in regular expressions is working well, but when i specify unicode codepoint rainge nothing comes out (u'00'). why is that am i doing some thing wrong.

Comment: @XPecto: Hm, it seems my regex contained the wrong kind of dash - must have become "autocorrected" somewhere. Can you try again?

Comment: @Tim: Now python returns the string itself without any change, http://pastebin.com/c78FWYcS

Comment: @XPecto: Ah, you're using Python 2. The `\uXXXX` escapes only work in Python 3. Python 2's `re` module isn't really strong on Unicode...

Comment: @Tim, I completely forgot this fact, what can i do, many decent open source libraries still need to be ported python 3.

Comment: In Python 2, you can paste the characters into your character class directly. Make sure your editor is configured to use `UTF-8` (which seems to be the case according to your script).

Comment: In Python 2 you must use Unicode strings for the pattern if you want Unicode semantics. `re.sub(r"[^ऀ-ॿ]+", "", mystring)` won't work because the things inside the character group are multiple bytes not single characters. `re.sub(ur"[^\u0900-\u097F]+", "", mystring)` is fine.

Comment: @bobince: Great, I didn't know that (neither did RegexBuddy; I'll let Jan Goyvaerts know :). The funny thing is that my regex appeared to work and yours didn't on the code sample linked above - but only because we had neglected to decode the page to Unicode :)

Comment: It's actually true that Python `re` doesn't understand the `\u` syntax, even in unicode patterns... the trick is that `ur` strings aren't completely raw. Unlike all other escapes, `\u` is still interpreted in unicode rawstring literals. So `u'\u1234'==ur'\u1234'` and `ur"[^\u0900-\u097F]+"` actually contains the characters `[^ऀ-ॿ]+` and not any backslashes. It's a weird and (IMO) undesirable behaviour, but it's useful here.

Comment: re.sub(ur"[^\u0900-\u097F]+", "", mystring) seems to also replace space characters with empty string. any suggestion of how the expression should be changed to exclude spaces also.

Comment: @SrijanSharma: Just add spaces (and other characters you want to keep) to the character class. Like `[^\u0900-\u097F\s]+`

Answer (score 2):

Using the [third-party regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you could express the pattern using [unicode scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script):

```
import regex
print(repr(regex.sub(ur'[^\p{Devanagari}\p{Han}]', u'', u'abc123\u0900'))) 
# u'\u0900'
```