# How to validate Nepali or Hindi word in HTML input form

Tags: html, regex, validation

I want user to input only the nepali language in the HTML input form. I had use the following regex

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

to avoid english alphabets and numbers but user are able to add other characters. Is there any other method or regex pattren to validate the nepali text or hindi text.

Comment: Fixing the logic, you may just add `^` and `$` anchors, `^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$`. But that will not restrict the input to only Nepali or Hindi chars.

Comment: But this will not solve my problem

Comment: How about `[\u0900-\u097F]+` for Hindi/Devanagari similar `\p{Devanagari}` which is not supported. Just an idea, also don't know how far this is supoprted in html5 forms validation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Isn't the pattern already anchored in html5 input validation?

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes, if it is used in the `pattern` attribute. We do not see where it is in the OP code

Answer (score 2):

Well if this is of help, I found it on [Config9.com](https://config9.com/linux/regex/regular-expressions-with-indian-characters/) and it's also mentioned in an [answer of @TimPietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23634004/5527985). JavaScript [supports](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint) syntax `\uFFFF` for Unicode. To match one or more Hindi/Devanagari chars:

```
[\u0900-\u097F]+
```

```html
<!-- input pattern test-->
<form>
  <input type="text" value="नेपाली" pattern="[\u0900-\u097F]+">
  <input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

If interested see the [Official Unicode Consortium **code chart for Devanagari** (PDF)](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf).

An equal [Unicode Script](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script) supported in [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC7), JGsoft, Ruby would probably be: `\p{Devanagari}`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a blacklist: describing what can't be used.

You could, instead, use a whitelist: describe what can be used.

I don't know this language, nor its characters. But it's possible to create a regex with a list of possible chars: `(शुन्य|सुन्ना|एक|दुई|तीन)+`

If the language allows, you can use a range, [from-to], like the `[a-z]+`.

Comment: But there are lots of character that i need. So using whitelist is impossible